How to optimize large KMZ file on map in react js?
I have more than 100 200 files on google map. Its start lagging and stuck the map.
The method i already implemented and tested are

throttledFetchKmzData
debouncedFetchKmzData
lazy laoding and cluster loading
togeojson - NPM  and Web Workers
But nothing is working. How to optimize large KMZ file on map in react js?


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
